# (UNITY) ¿Como borrar posicion del jugador al cambiar de escena?

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

espero no molestar, pero tengo una pregunta:
Estoy haciendo un juego en Unity 2D y necesito que al cambiar de escena se borre la posicion del jugador, he seguido unos tutoriales en YouTube pero nada, solo explican como crear el archivo (en binario) y como cargarlo. Espero que no sea un problema ni una molestia, pero, ¿Alguien podría explicarlo o pasar un enlace a algun sitio donde lo explican? Muchas gracias, paso codigo por si tengo un error de codigo o es que esta mal hecho.

Gracias

CODIGO:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    public static void guardarPosicion(Movimiento player) //Accede al script de Movimiento del Jugador
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedPlayer.run";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData(player);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static PlayerData cargarPosicion()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedPlayer.run";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            PlayerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Archivo no encontrado...");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static PlayerData borrarPosicion()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedPlayer.run";

        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        PlayerData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
        File.Delete();

        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu lo que quieres es borrar un fichero, esto se hace así:

```
public static void borrarPosicion()
{
    string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedPlayer.run";
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Delete(path)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Pero si es más o menos lo que ya está haciendo

Comment: @Mateo Para nada, él en su función está creando un nuevo fichero cosa que sobra, básicamente esta haciendo lo mismo que `cargarPosicion()`, y luego llama `File.Delete` sin argumentos cosa que no se puede hacer

Comment: Cierto, me despisté.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, si que funciona :D